# jQuery Mobile Accordion not expanding (KnockoutJS)

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js, accordion, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm using jQuery Mobile and KnockoutJS and can't get the Accordion widget to work. You can find an example of what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/NYTQC/1/. The accordion panels does not expand when clicked.  Can anyone explain what I have done wrong and perhaps show how to correct the code? In my real project the observable knockout collection will be updated dynamically via a REST service depending on user actions.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d">
   <!-- ko foreach: collection -->
      <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h3><span data-bind="text: caption"></span></h3>
         <span>TODO</span>
      </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout, JQMobile, and generating a collapsible-set doesn't quite seem to work right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313853/knockout-jqmobile-and-generating-a-collapsible-set-doesnt-quite-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem and found the solution in the following link

http://jsfiddle.net/MauriceG/8QGU5/show/light/

```
// clean up borders
collapsiblesInSet.each( function() {
    $( this ).jqmRemoveData( "collapsible-last" )
        .find( $.mobile.collapsible.prototype.options.heading )
        .find( "a" ).first()
        .removeClass( "ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom" )
        .find( ".ui-btn-inner" )
        .removeClass( "ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom" );
});
```

The code accomponied is just a portion of what is required, You just view page source of the attached link and come to your own understanding about how the solution works.